# Ubuntu webcam ID

Tags: ubuntu, webcam

I have calibration matrices for several webcameras in a laboratory. When I plug in a webcam, I should be able to identify it using some type of ID, and then use the appropriate calibration matrix. The problem is that many cameras have the same vendor and product ID, so lsusb is useless. For instance, with two cameras plugged in,

```
sudo lsusb | grep -i cam
```

yields

```
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 0458:708c KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) Genius WideCam F100
Bus 003 Device 019: ID 0458:708c KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) Genius WideCam F100
```

Furthermore, if I take one out and put another one in its place, the command

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/video1
```

yields exactly the same file (although USEC_INITIALIZED does change):

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/video4linux/video1
N: video1
S: v4l/by-id/usb-KYE_Systems_Corp._USB_Camera_200901010001-video-index0
S: v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-video-index0
E: COLORD_DEVICE=1
E: COLORD_KIND=camera
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-video-index0 /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-KYE_Systems_Corp._USB_Camera_200901010001-video-index0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/video1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/video4linux/video1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=video4linux-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_3_1_0
E: ID_MODEL=USB_Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB_Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ID=708c
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_3_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0427
E: ID_SERIAL=KYE_Systems_Corp._USB_Camera_200901010001
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=200901010001
E: ID_TYPE=video
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=uvcvideo
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:0e0100:0e0200:010100:010200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_V4L_CAPABILITIES=:capture:
E: ID_V4L_PRODUCT=USB_Camera
E: ID_V4L_VERSION=2
E: ID_VENDOR=KYE_Systems_Corp.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=KYE\x20Systems\x20Corp.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0458
E: MAJOR=81
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=video4linux
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=20837504187
```

So the serial number being reported to `udevadm` appears to be the same for several devices. I don't understand how that can be the case.

So the question is... what are my options? Am I missing a command to get the serial number that isn't being reported to `udevadm`?

Comment: Do you know that the cameras should have unique serial numbers? It seems like something that would be skipped when cheaply mass producing them.

Comment: I just assumed that each device would have its own serial number. I don't know if that is the case. In fact, from the data being put out, it seems like they do not have unique serial numbers. I just have never come across this before.

Comment: In lieu of a serial number, is there any other way I could automatically distinguish them?